# Express the $n$th smallest number in this set in terms of $n$

Tags: number-theory

> Suppose $n$ is a perfect square. Consider the set of all numbers which are the product of two numbers, not necessarily distinct, both of which are at least $n$. Express the $n$th smallest number in this set in terms of $n$.

If, for example, $n = 4$, then the numbers are $4^2, 4 \cdot 5, 4 \cdot 6, 5^2$. If $n = 9$, then the numbers are $9^2,9 \cdot 10, 9 \cdot 11, 10^2, 9 \cdot 12, 10 \cdot 11,9 \cdot 13, 10 \cdot 12, 11^2$. Thus we conjecture the answer is $(n+\sqrt{n}-1)^2$, but how do we prove this?

Comment: that number isn't an integer for most $n$ I think.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Recall that $n$ is a perfect square.

Comment: oh, my bad.${}{}{}$

Comment: Why do you think that number works?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Because I tested it for some examples and it was true.

Comment: Do you know the GM-AM.  (n+k)(n+k) < (n+(k-a))(n+(k+a)) the numbers in order will be n, (n+1)n,(n+1)(n+1),n (n+2), (n+1)(n+2),n (n+3) and so on.  Can you take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there $w=(n+\sqrt n -1)^2$ is at least the $n$'th number in the list.

We must only prove that $w<ab$ if $a+b>2n+2\sqrt{n}-2$, with both $a$ and $b\geq n$.

Clearly this product is minimized in the case $a=n$, Which leaves $b>n+2\sqrt{n}-2$, since $b$ is an integer we can take the minimal case $b=n+\sqrt{2n}-1$.

So we must only prove $n(n+2\sqrt{n}-1)\geq (n+\sqrt{n}-1)^2\iff -n>-2n-2\sqrt{n}+n+1=-n-2\sqrt{n}+1$.

So it is in fact true.

Comment: Why is $w$ at least the $n$th number in the list?